# KnockoutJS how to make different ViewModels work toghether?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Suppose i have a main view that contains

- A bookable item
- A shopping cart

Both elements are in the same page, each of them has its own VM, like this:

```
<div id='page'>
    <div id='item'>
        <span data-bind='text: item().name'></span>
        <span data-bind='text: item().price'></span> EUR

        <!-- What to bind on this click handler? -->
        <button>Add</button>
    </div>

    <hr>

    <div id='cart'>
        You have 0 items in your cart.
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function ItemVM() {
    var self = this;
    self.item = ko.observable({id: 1, name:'test', price: 3.99});
}

function CartVM() {
    var self = this;

    // Adds an item to cart.
    self.add = function(item) {
        // Business logic here
    }

    // And so on, other methods here.
    self.remove = function(item) {}
    self.checkout = function() {}
}

ko.applyBindings(new ItemVM(), document.getElementById('item'));
ko.applyBindings(new CartVM(), document.getElementById('cart'));
```

I have 2 questions.

1) How to use a click handler, within the 'item' context, that is defined elsewhere? In other words, how to make the button use CartVM.add() as the click handler?

2) Is there something wrong i am doing in reference to KO or MVVM itself?

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/q8uWW/)

Answer (score 1):

The idea of the MVVM pattern is to have a view bound to a single viewModel. Then you will have data objects described in the model.

In the situtation you have I tend to favour composition. So if I have a view composed of functional elements I tend to compose the viewModel of these separate elements.

I do find this overall is easier. It's likely the container VM will have some elements that are actually part of the individual page. It's probably hard to follow if there are a lot of individual viewModels that are part of the page. The other issue is that cart is coupled to one container div. In the case of cart this may be acceptable. In other cases your functional component may have view elements which may be hard to contain under one div so it becomes hard to segregate viewModels like this.

I've amended your design with:

Note I add a call to add in the itemVM as shown.

```
function ItemVM() {

    this.add = function(data, e) {
        viewModel.CartVM.add(data);
    };
}

function VM() {
     this.ItemVM = new ItemVM();
     this.CartVM = new CartVM();
}

var viewModel = new VM();
ko.applyBinding(viewModel);
```

fiddle to illustrate this here: http://jsfiddle.net/q8uWW/4/

HTH

Comment: This seems to be a valid solution, anyway it will lead to duplicate code as i need to wrap any Item/Cart methods in the container VM, which i dont like much

Comment: Have amended above to illustrate why I generally use composition to create one viewModel per view

Answer (score 0):

An example using my binding convention library, it makes it easy to work with multiple view models. https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/Knockout.BindingConventions

To communicate between models you can use a Event Aggregate pattern, I have one in a library called SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy, if you have no use for SignalR you can extract the eventaggregatorn part. https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/

The idea with my convention library is to use template bindings for each view model. Like

```
<div id='page'>
    <div id='item' data-name="item"></div>

    <hr>

    <div id='cart' data-name="cart"></div>
</div>

<script id="ItemView" type="text/html">
    <span data-name='name'></span>
    <span data-name='price'></span> EUR

    <button data-name="add">Add</button>
</script>

<script id="CartView" type="text/html">
    You have <span data-name="count"></span> items in your cart.
</script>
```

Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/hL5rY/